# How do I connect 2 Screens on flutter?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I'm trying to create a Login and sign up page. How to make it go from the login screen to sign up page when pressed "Don't Have an Account?". Do I need to create 2 dart files? one for the login screen and one for the sign up screen.

*Also How can I align the "Forgot Password?" Text to the right side?*

This is my login screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    Color hexToColor(String code) {
      return new Color(int.parse(code.substring(1, 7), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
    }
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: "Welcome to Flutter",
        home: new Material(
            child: new Container (
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                color: Colors.grey[850],
                child: new Container(
                  child: new Center(
                      child: new Column(
                          children : [
                            new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 140.0)),
                            new Text('Welcome!', //heading
                              style: new TextStyle(color: hexToColor("#ffffff"), fontSize: 30.0),),
                            new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0)),
                            // email text field is below
                            new TextFormField(
                              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                labelText: "Enter Email",
                                fillColor: Colors.blue,
                                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(17.0),
                                  borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                  ),
                                ),
                                //fillColor: Colors.green
                              ),
                              validator: (val) {
                                if(val.length==0) {
                                  return "Email cannot be empty";
                                }else{
                                  return null;
                                }
                              },
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "Poppins",
                              ),
                            ),

                            new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),


                            //password text field is below
                            new TextFormField(
                              obscureText: true,
                              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                labelText: "Enter Password",
                                fillColor: Colors.blue,
                                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(17.0),
                                  borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                  ),
                                ),
                                //fillColor: Colors.green
                              ),
                              validator: (val) {
                                if(val.length==0) {
                                  return "Password cannot be empty";
                                }else{
                                  return null;
                                }
                              },
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "Poppins",
                              ),
                            ),
                            new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),

                            new Text("Forgot Password?", style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              color: Colors.grey[800],
                              fontFamily: "Poppins",
                              letterSpacing: 1.2,

                            ),
                            ),
                            new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0)),

                            //Login button below
                            RaisedButton (
                              onPressed: () {},
                              color: Colors.amber,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75.0, 10.0, 75.0, 10.0),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17)),
                              child: Text("Login", style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                letterSpacing: 1.2,
                              ),),
                            ),
                            new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 150.0)),

                            new Text(
                              "Don't Have an Account?",

                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15.0,
                                letterSpacing: 1.2,
                              ),
                            ),


                          ]
                      )
                  ),
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new file for register, and use Navigator.push to navigate to register screen. You can wrap your Text in an InkWell or GestureDetector widget and trigger navigate action with onTap()

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegisterPage()) // this is you register page
    );
  },
  child: new Text(
    "Don't Have an Account?",
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 15.0,
      letterSpacing: 1.2,
    ),
  ),
)
```

To align your "Forgot Password?" string, wrap it in a Row widget and set MainAxisAlignment.end

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [
    new Text(
      "Forgot Password?",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15.0,
        color: Colors.grey[800],
        fontFamily: "Poppins",
        letterSpacing: 1.2
      )
    )
  ]
)
```

register.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterPageState createState() => _RegisterPageState();
}

class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {

}
```

Comment: I have to create a new dart file for the registration right?

Comment: you should, for better maintenance in the future. If you put all your registration code in the same file with login code, the code will be extremely long and hard to read. Later in the development, when you need to add code for login action, registration action and validation for email, password, it'll be even longer.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering I'm quite new, Let's say the register file is "register.dart" , when I add it like this ```MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => (register.dart)``` gives me an error to define it

Comment: when you navigate to a new screen, you have to put the name of the widget, not the name of the file. For example, in your current code, MyApp is the name of your widget / login screen. And when you want to navigate to your login screen, you have to put MyApp(). Same as that, you will create a register.dart file, and the name of your widget should be something like Register(), so you have to add it like this MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Register()

Comment: i've added register.dart in my answer